# Filling a column with multiple values

Tags: excel, vba

I have an unusual problem. I have a spreadsheet full of data ranging from columns A:J. I want to add a further column, K, and populate it with names of Staff. The idea is that each staff member is given an allocation of the spreadsheet. The numbers for the allocation are already calculated in another sheet, and referenced in this spreadsheet in columns M and N. M2 and down contains the staff names, N2 and down contains their corresponding allocation.

My problem is figuring out how to fill column K with this data. For example APerson (M2) has an allocation of 23(N2), I want to populate K2 (Row 1 being the header) to K24 with APerson's name. After that, I would like to allocate APerson2(M3) with say, 15(N3), which would then start at K25. I have a feeling it will involve loops but my VBA knowledge is patchy and looking around I can only find loops which fill with incremental numbers.

Edit: Apologies for not attaching any files; this was initially posted via my phone as stackoverflow is blocked at my work. I printed my work-in-progress code out so i'll type it up ASAP.

Edit 2: Here's my code so far. I've got the allocation working - kind of.

```
Sub Allocate()
name1 = Range("M2").Value
countto = Range("N2").Value

Range("K1").Select
 Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    For Counter = 1 To countto
        ActiveCell.Value = name1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next Counter

name2 = Range("M3").Value
countto2 = Range("N3").Value

Range("K1").Select
 Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    For Counter2 = 1 To countto2
        ActiveCell.Value = name2
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next Counter2
End Sub
```

Is there any way to make this automatically assign 'name1', 'name2' and so on, for a large number (20+) staff without having to manually type it all, or any tips on how to make it more efficient?

Comment: Hi Sozmarra. 1) This forum is for programmers with a decent level of programming experience. 2) It is normal to post your current script so we can help improve or take out the error. 3) For building basic knowledge on programming (VBA) find a training on or offline. Good luck

Comment: Sozmara -> for more help on how to structure your question to get an answer that can really help, read [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq). If you edit your post with some more content of what you've tried, we can definitely pitch in and get you what you need.

Comment: @Sozmarra If you show some effort by starting the code and then post the code on here, asking how to make it work effectively, you will most likely get some quick help. This doesn't look like a complex process

Comment: This should be evidence enough to your network admins that Stack Overflow should be whitelisted, at least for you, or on a provisional basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you have some basic knowledge of VB and I'm a bit rusty, this is a rush job until someone gives you a better answer.  It assumes that on your source sheet theree is a different name on each row consecutively and then a blank row.

```
enter code here

Sub Allocate()
i3 = 2     'counter for DESTINATION sheet
i1 = 2     'counter for SOURCE sheet

Do until sheets(source).cells(i1, N#).value = ""     'until the last name
    NAME = sheets(source).cells(i1, N#).value         'N#: column NUMBER containing names
    ENTRIES = Sheets(Source).cells(i1, C#).value      'C#: column NUMBER containing numbers
    For i2 = 1 to ENTRIES
        Sheets(Dest).ceklls(i3, 11).value = NAME             '11 is column K
        i3 = i3 + 1
    Next
i1 = i1 + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting the code to be so small. That does the job perfectly. Thanks a lot.